# what is the best book for calculus?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I am looking for the best calculus book to use it to teach myself calculus.
I have already had a bit of a search and these are what I have come up so far, But I have no idea which one is truly the best bet here and of more value in terms of being good at a self-study manner with lots of explanations and charts for every concepts and chapters.
Here is the list i have so far:

1. James stewart calculus 7e
2. Calculus -Richard A. Silverman
3. The Calculus 7: Louis Leithold

**Update:**
I am a Computer Science student and i need it for my courses and carrier, so please consider this in your answers.
If there is any better book please mention it since i have no idea on these books.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Spivak's Calculus is usually consdered a good book.

Comment: I'd go for 1. Great book with many examples and good explanations, plus lots of exercises. (If the one you're referring to is the same as Calculus Early Transcendentals at least, that's the one I know from Stewart).

Comment: Main question: Do you want to learn calculus as a potential mathematician would or do you want to learn it computationally for science/engineering applications? The answers to your question hinge on your answer to this.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I am a Computer Science student and i need it for my courses and carrier. So its the latter one :)

Comment: I would suggest you look at Rogawski or Edwards & Penney. Stewart is ok, too.

Comment: Analysis for Computer Scientists by Michael Oberguggenberger and Alexander Ostermann is especially for CS students. http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-0-85729-445-6

Answer (score 4):

Thomas Finney book on Calculus is a very good one .

Answer (score 3):

Integral calculus by Shanti Narayan is an excellent book. I would reccomend it.