# What would be a good self study textbook for 1-variable calculus with a pinch of multivariable?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation, learning

About 10 years ago I took calculus 1 and 2.
I know a few basics.
Like integrals are good for areas of curves. And derivatives are good for finding relative slopes.
I have decent grasp of simple derivation/integration like the power rule. However I get really confused with more complex stuff like the quotient rule.
I passed calculus with an A and I dunno how. Now I'm looking for something that'll me grasp calc better for up coming classes 10 years later. (I dont have my old school book).
I'm currently pursuing a chemistry/engineering major.
What would be a good self study textbook for 1-variable calculus with a pinch of multivariable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: May I know what is your purpose for studying this again ?

Comment: Jose, I did as you asked.

Comment: @SiKucing I'm using it as a reference book and something to help me prepare for physics and other possible sciences. I am an engineering/chemistry major.

Comment: If you don't want to be rigorous, a good standard calculus book that also emphasizes on application is Steward's Calculus: Early Transcendentals. Spivak's and Apostol's aim for serious audience such as math majors. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472838/what-is-the-best-book-for-calculus for further suggestion. Maybe will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal recommendation is [Thomas' Calculus, 14th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134438981). It covers all of single-variable calculus with sufficient depth(not as rigorous as Spivak's Calculus, but reasonable for your purposes), and also dives into multivariable calculus upto Green's Theorem. As an alternative to textbook, [Khan Academy's](https://www.khanacademy.org) Calculus course is pretty neat for brushing up.

Comment: Since you mentioned in the comments that you need a Calculus textbook for applications in sciences, Thomas' Calculus certainly has the upper edge because the problem sets contain a variety of questions catering to those in sciences and engineering.